# How to add multilanguage support to a Yocto build?

Tags: linux, utf-8, internationalization, locale, yocto

I'm trying to add multilanguage support to a Yocto build. Reading the official documentation I've found that the build options that controls locale settings are:

- GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES
- IMAGE_LINGUAS

Link: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES

After a build with the following options:

```
GLIBC_GENERATE_LOCALES="en_GB.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8"
IMAGE_LINGUAS?="en-gb"
```

if I ask to "localectl" the list of available locales, nothing is displayed (command: localectl list-locales).

Another bit of info, the output of the "locale" command is:

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

The output of "locale -a" command is:

```
C
POSIX
```

What am I missing?

Comment: After further investigations I've found that the IMAGE_LINGUAS options was overwritten into another configuration file. After the solution of this conflict I've found the following locales installed: "en_US", "en_GB". This is not enough, what I'm looking for is:"en_US.utf8". Why the utf8 version of the locale has not beed installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locales were not generated because the IMAGE_LINGUAS variable was overwritten into another place (my fault).

The locales generated with IMAGE_LINGUAS, e.g. "en_GB" or "en_US", does not have the ".UTF-8" suffix in their name but they use the UTF-8 encoding. To check if a locale is UTF-8 refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797421/5321161